# What is the difference between Libera and Libra?

Tags: translation-explanation

I noticed a company's name Libratone emphasizing that their company name meant "set sound free."

> "LIBRA•TONE Our mission is in our name; Libratone – set sound free."

Does Libera work as well here? I don't know Latin nor conjugations - just a curious individual asking.

Comment: It may be from French _libre_ rather than Latin _libera_ - or at least, influenced by the French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's in fact quite a significant difference here!

The adjective [*līber, lībera, līberum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dliber1) means "free"; it's the root of the English words "liberty" and "liberation".

The noun [*lībra, lībrae*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlibra) means "scales" (for weighing things) or "pound" (as weighed out on a scale). It's the origin of the abbreviations "lb" and "£", and the constellation Libra.

So if you want "free", you need the "e" in there. It doesn't work without it.

Comment: Right - doing my own research lead me to a similar understanding. I guess the company "Libratone" just wanted to be a bit creative or simple with their naming convention.

Comment: It could presumably mean "the noise of scales".

Comment: @fdb: Hah true. Or it could simply be an error...